# How to save image encoding into mysql database?

Tags: database, encoding, decoding

I'm using python face recognition library to recognize unknown faces.
I get this type of encoding in face_encoding. What is it and how to store this encoding into MySQL database.

```
[-0.07152465  0.10215988  0.01136428 -0.0308747  -0.16287753 -0.03153189
 -0.06578728 -0.14805837  0.15640661 -0.07523477  0.14867496  0.04072035
 -0.16808468 -0.00982519 -0.02270632  0.08025806 -0.20561409 -0.12184067
 -0.11708203 -0.09774955 -0.06495257  0.02422624  0.00922573  0.01991012
 -0.13370116 -0.20686181 -0.1488608  -0.12282808  0.18252769 -0.08956295
  0.0171157   0.07873753 -0.1460952  -0.09000996  0.06861175  0.13834456
 -0.07108913 -0.01959831  0.20239949  0.05026209 -0.15374154 -0.01580941
  0.06390329  0.27492422  0.25704402  0.08602936  0.03448958 -0.04159172
  0.14044689 -0.21021228  0.06922252  0.15272671  0.21329369  0.10292344
  0.08227161 -0.22346584  0.09088185  0.14461374 -0.1744801   0.11717336
  0.13315231 -0.16698143  0.00260702  0.07305491  0.18898451  0.10911863
 -0.01746466 -0.16348183  0.23652273 -0.22252038 -0.06905969  0.12435962
 -0.07139365 -0.08369306 -0.24058753 -0.06713018  0.39160824  0.16331878
 -0.09675828 -0.01672895 -0.0439845  -0.05550656  0.00398231  0.04980896
 -0.17432253 -0.07968439 -0.12069637 -0.02069626  0.22844598 -0.00178664
  0.06633241  0.1762405   0.02624917 -0.00859033  0.03681781 -0.02436156
 -0.13713233 -0.03320267 -0.03164122 -0.09198754  0.03632114 -0.15644331
  0.04891206  0.11745825 -0.20992307  0.17861255 -0.07077605  0.00281386
 -0.03633321 -0.04432689 -0.02048816  0.02499891  0.28510362 -0.21085122
  0.21044926  0.21076941 -0.06554883  0.08499552  0.05917196  0.1140425
 -0.05485246 -0.04627831 -0.15220977 -0.10018148 -0.06419093 -0.15043713
  0.02276208  0.0441333 ]
```

I want to store this type of encoding into a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize this data using [pickle.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) and pass it to the BLOB field of your database. Then use `pickle.loads()` to deserialize stored data.

Example:

```
import pickle
import MySQLdb

## Pickle the list into a string
face_pickled_data = pickle.dumps(face_encoding)

## Connect to the database
connection = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','user','pass','myDatabase')

## Create a cursor for interacting
cursor = connection.cursor()

## Add the information to the database table
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO faces VALUES (NULL, 'faceName', %s)""", (face_pickled_data, ))

## Select what we just added
cursor.execute("""SELECT data FROM faces WHERE name = 'faceName'""")

## Dump the results to a string
rows = cursor.fetchall()

## Get the results
for each in rows:
    ## The result is also in a tuple
    for face_stored_pickled_data in each:
        face_data = pickle.loads(face_stored_pickled_data)
```

Comment: But this will not allow you to perform searches on that data